# How to change the name on a ticket booked through the Wizz Discount Club?

Tags: air-travel, wizz-air

I am a Wizzair Discount Club member and I have booked a ticket from Macedonia to Germany. I have written the wrong name, so how can I change it?

[image]

Is it possible? I can't do check in because I'm not from the EU, and they check the card at the airport.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a question for their helpdesk?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's out of scope for this site.

Comment: If I could, I would vote not to close this as off topic because it is very much in scope as it is a problem that is related to travel on a specific airline, and we have happily fielded and answered similar questions before.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas The answer is to call the airline. It's next to impossible to change a name even on an airline ticket that wasn't booked with points, so short of a WizzAir agent working some magic, I don't see what the OP hopes to get from us.

Comment: @Choster - Sounds like an answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple - **call the airline**. If it's possible to change the name they would be the only ones capable of doing so.

Comment: I will confirm that contacting the airline solved my coworker's issue. In his case, it was free of charge. More info about it: he started the free check in and he is flying in the next 40 hours.